# Can I fill in the visit visa application for my wife?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

Can I fill in the visit visa application on behalf of my wife who lives in the Philippines if I'm currently living in the UK? It will have my e-mail address in case someone from the appropriate agency who will be handling the visa has any questions regarding the application.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I have done this twice on behalf of my partner (visa approved both times). Your wife remains responsible for the information provided in the application so you should make sure she checks a draft for accuracy before you submit it online.

Comment: Having the actual applicant check all answers is very, very important. Similarly, she should check any answers to questions before you send them.